# JQuery not responding to browser resize

Tags: jquery, window-resize

I have a responsive menu that changes from horizontal to vertical based on the width of the browser. Both versions of the menu reveal hidden divs when categories are clicked. Both of them are working properly but only if the browser is resized and then reloaded. If the browser is not reloaded, the new window size isn't calculated and it turns into an ugly mess.

Here is my JSFiddle that demonstrates my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/oxnerebo/

If your browser is greater than 500px, the menu categories will be horizontal and the hidden divs will toggle below, spanning the width of all categories.

If your browser is less than 500px, the menu categories will be stacked on top of one another and the hidden divs will toggle below the div that was selected.

Please help me figure out how I can resize the browser WITHOUT reloading and switch between these two versions of the menu.

HTML:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
<div class="wrap">
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div class="hiddenDiv1"></div>
<div class="hiddenDiv2"></div>
<div class="hiddenDiv3"></div></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var screenWidth = $(window).width();

if(screenWidth < 500) {
    $('.hiddenDiv1').appendTo($('#div1'));
        $('.hiddenDiv2').appendTo($('#div2'));
};


  $("#div1, .hiddenDiv1").click(function(){
    $(".hiddenDiv1").slideToggle();
    $(".hiddenDiv2").hide();
    $(".hiddenDiv3").hide();
  });
  $("#div2, .hiddenDiv2").click(function(){
    $(".hiddenDiv2").slideToggle();
    $(".hiddenDiv1").hide();
    $(".hiddenDiv3").hide();
  });
  $("#div3, .hiddenDiv3").click(function(){
    $(".hiddenDiv3").slideToggle();
    $(".hiddenDiv1").hide();
    $(".hiddenDiv2").hide();
  });
```

CSS:

```
   #mainContainer {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        clear:both;
    }
    .wrap{
        margin:0 auto;
        position:relative;
        max-width:900px;
        overflow:visible;
        clear:both;
    }
    #div1, #div2, #div3 {
        float:left;
        height:auto;
        padding:5px 0 5px 0;
        width:33.333%;
        display:inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    #div1:hover, #div2:hover, #div3:hover {

    }
    #div1{
        background:orange;
    }
    #div2{
        background:green;
    }
    #div3{
        background:blue;
    }

    .hiddenDiv1, .hiddenDiv2, .hiddenDiv3{
        display:none;
        height:100px;
        width:100%;
        max-width:900px;
        clear:both;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .hiddenDiv1{
        background:orange;
    }
    .hiddenDiv2{
        background:green;
    }
    .hiddenDiv3{
        background:blue;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px){
        #div1, #div2, #div3 {
            width: 100%;
            display: block; 
        }
        .hiddenDiv1, .hiddenDiv2, .hiddenDiv3 {
            width:100%;
        }
    }
```

PS: I've done a lot of research on this site but this is my very first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try adding a handler to the resize event:

```
//initial call to function for if page loads under the width threshold
move_elements();

$(window).resize(function () {
    move_elements();
});

function move_elements() {
    screenWidth = $(window).width();

    //using insertAfter instead so the div is not inside the menu div, causes issues with the click otherwise
    if (screenWidth < 500) {
        $('.hiddenDiv1').insertAfter($('#div1'));
        $('.hiddenDiv2').insertAfter($('#div2'));
        $('.hiddenDiv3').insertAfter($('#div3'));
    } else {
        $('.hiddenDiv1, .hiddenDiv2, .hiddenDiv3').insertAfter($('#div3')); //properly done for extended width, credits to ScoobSays
    }
}
```

<s>In action:
http://jsfiddle.net/k74gtcc1/1/</s>

ScoobSays edit for 900px+ width: [jsfiddle.net/d47t70pm](http://jsfiddle.net/d47t70pm)

Comment: WinnieThePooh, thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. When I reach the required 15 points of reputation I will upvote your solution.

Comment: I altered one small portion of your script to make sure the hidden divs were centered when revealed on a screen wider than the max-width of 900 px. All I did was change:

else {
        $('.hiddenDiv1').insertAfter($('.wrap'));
        $('.hiddenDiv2').insertAfter($('.wrap'));
        $('.hiddenDiv3').insertAfter($('.wrap'));
    }

to: 

else {
        $('.hiddenDiv1, .hiddenDiv2, .hiddenDiv3').insertAfter($('#div3'));
    }

Link to modified JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d47t70pm/